# Is HTML5 fully functinable in all mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, mobile-browser

I just made a website from scratch. I used HTML, CSS, jquery, javascript and php. 
I haven't published that yet. I just ran it in my localhost with all commonly used browser, and it works fine.

Now before I publish that online I need to know few things.

```
1. DO I need to do anything special in order to be able to run that on public server?

2. Will my site work fine in all mobile phone browsers?
```

Comment: you can see a list of html5 support in mobile browsers at http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Considering html5 is [not a standard yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) or it is a [living standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) depending on who you ask there is no such thing as "will html5 work in x"

Answer (score 3):

1. Depends on structure, technologies, etc. Just try and look what will broke.
2. http://html5test.com/

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your second question:

You can use http://caniuse.com/ do validate if your used technologies can be used in all mobile browsers.
Some Browsers don't support some singel parts of HTML5. So it might be the best to check each single technology that you are using.